# angular how to get countries in different languages using i18n-iso-countries package

Tags: angular

In my Angular  application I am trying to get country names in Arabic language only and keep its code in English using i18n-iso-countries library. I installed it using npm

npm -i i18n-iso-countries

Then in my component I imported it like this:

import * as i18IsoCountries from 'i18n-iso-countries';

I tried to replace en with ar but it doesn't work

```
getCountries(): { id: string; name: string }[] {
  return Object.entries(countriesLib.getNames('ar', { select: 'official' })).map((entry) => {
    return {
      id: entry[0],
      name: entry[1]
    };
  });
}
getCountry(countryKey: string): string {
  return countriesLib.getName(countryKey, 'en');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to import ar language json file

```
countriesLib.registerLocale(require('i18n-iso-countries/langs/ar.json'));
```